# No css/js or images found on heroku deployment octobercms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku, octobercms

I have deployed my octobercms site on heroku successfully but it is not loading any css/js or image file. All links go to 404. External links are loaded but no local link is working. I have deployed it using Github.

I have tried all of solutions I found anywhere on web but none of them works. All laravel solutions are not working. I can't even access any file manually. Functionality of site is working normally.

currently this is how links are included:

```
  <link type="text/css" href="{{'assets/css/custom.css'| theme}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this is how they are shown when rendered:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://pandak-farms.herokuapp.com/themes/codejunkie/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

links should open but all of them are pointing to 404.
demo: http://pandak-farms.herokuapp.com/themes/codejunkie/assets/css/argon.css?v=1.0.1

Comment: I checked link seems its working now, can you share what was issue and its solution, i guess it should be some .htaccess related issue.

Comment: Yes, mainly it was htaccess issue. When I force https this there is still mixed content issue and I can't find any solution to that but it is working on http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Just setting up an env variable fixes the mixed content issue. set LINK_POLICY to 'secure' either in the .env file or in the config/cms.php